# I cant get mod_gzip to function properly

Tags: gzip, compression

The [pagespeed](http://see.weareinto.com/Gj54) tool says

```
Compressing http://72.10.33.203/workspace/js/plugins.min.js could save 95.0KiB (66% reduction).
```

but when I [test for GZIP](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/?url=aHR0cDovLzcyLjEwLjMzLjIwMy93b3Jrc3BhY2UvanMvcGx1Z2lucy5taW4uanM=) it shows that it works.

I have my htaccess and conf files setup correctly (i think).

How can I verify?
Is the pagespeed tool wrong?
How to I make this work?

Comment: The page in question is http://72.10.33.203/workspace/js/plugins.min.js

Answer (score 2):

See web server response headers using firebug in firefox or developer tools in chrome:

If resource is gzipped you will see header:

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
```

You can also use any CLI web clients, e.g. wget:

```
wget -S -O /dev/null http://72.10.33.203/workspace/js/plugins.min.js
```

It doesn't show content-encoding, but if you use

```
wget --header='Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch' -S -O /dev/null`
```

Connecting to 72.10.33.203:80... connected.

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Fri, 18 May 2012 19:51:12 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Last-Modified: Fri, 18 May 2012 19:42:04 GMT
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
  Expires: Sat, 18 May 2013 19:51:12 GMT
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Content-Encoding: gzip   <================================ Look here
  X-Powered-By: PleskLin
  Connection: close
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Right, I don't see it on [here](http://see.weareinto.com/GitZ)

Comment: I've tested your url with `wget -S -O /dev/null http://72.10.33.203/workspace/js/plugins.min.js`
It doesn't show content-encoding.

but when I use `wget --header='Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch' -S -O /dev/null http://72.10.33.203/workspace/js/plugins.min.js`

content-encoding is set properly and response size is smaller.

so, your mod_gzip is set up properly

Comment: Thank you!! it turns out my company network somehow prevents that header. Thank you!

Comment: If you can please edit your answer to reflect the comment, i will award

Comment: Well, i thought that was the answer, but even off the network, the google pagetool utility and the headers tools still dont work

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with it http://my.opera.com/OmegaJunior/blog/google-chrome-and-gzip

Comment: and this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962721/pre-compressed-gzip-break-on-chrome-why

Comment: sorry, i was incorrect.. this was not the answer.

Comment: @KirkStrobeck Many corporate proxy servers don't support compressed encoding as they'd have to decompress and recompress that content to filter/scan/classify it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `.htaccess`

```
<Files *.js.gz>
ForceType text/javascript
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</Files>
<Files *.css.gz>
ForceType text/css
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</Files>
<Files *.html.gz>
ForceType text/html
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</Files>
```